# Simplifying a rational expression with a quadratic factor

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given:$$(8 + x)^{2} + \frac{16(8 + x)^{2}}{x^{2}} =$$
$$\frac{x^{2}(8 + x)^{2} + 16(8 + x)^{2}}{x^{2}} =$$
$$\frac{(8 + x)^{2}(x^{2} + 16)}{x^{2}} \Rightarrow$$
I get to this point but somehow it goes to this:
$$(8 + x)^{2}(1 + \frac{16}{x^{2}})$$
How is it done? Thanks

Comment: $\dfrac{x^2+16}{x^2}=1+\dfrac{16}{x^2}$

Comment: Just factor out $(8+x)^2$.

Comment: Why the down votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{(8 + x)^{2}(x^{2} + 16)}{x^{2}}$$
$$=(8+x)^2\cdot \frac{x^2+16}{x^2}$$
$$=(8+x)^2\cdot\left(1+\frac{16}{x^2}\right)$$